# Trouble getting relationship right between two comboboxes and the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `StackPanel` which contains a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboMeetingWeek" ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}"
    DisplayMemberPath="DateMeetingAsText"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Meeting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ComboBox>
```

The main **window** is bound to a `DataContext` called `OCLMEditorModelView`. Thus, in the above ComboBox it is bound to the **Meetings** property. The list of items are all of type **Meeting** (from the list).

Further down I have this `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboChairman" IsEditable="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Chairman, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Students, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:OtherPrivileges.Chairman}, Converter={StaticResource StudentPrivilegeConvertor}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="Students"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

**As it is** I get names showing up in my combo using:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Students, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:OtherPrivileges.Chairman}, 
Converter={StaticResource StudentPrivilegeConvertor}, 
Mode=OneWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I think this is correct, because for the combo, its DataContext is still the main one `OCLMEditorModelView`. So it finds the **Students** list and fills it with names. Good.

But this bit fails:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Chairman, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Chairman is a member of the Meeting property. And the Meeting property was bound to SelectedItem of the combo. So I have a problem.

> OCLMEditorModelView.Meetings
>
> OCLMEditorModelView.Meetings.Meeting
>
> OCLMEditorModelView.Meetings.Meeting.Chairman
>
> OCLMEditorModelView.Students
>
> OCLMEditorModelView.Students.Name

```
Main Window (OCLMEditorModelView)
    DateCombo (Meetings (property of OCLMEditorModelView instance))
        SelectedItem (Meeting (property of Meetings instance)

    NamesCombo 
        ItemsSource (Students (property of OCLMEditorModelView instance))
            SelectedItem (Chairman (property of the aforementioned Meeting instance.
```

In addition, since these combo boxes are editable, the name might not be an actual item in the list. So it would have to be a value.

Update: What am I trying to achieve?

`comboMeetingWeek` contains a bunch of `Meeting` items.

As you select a meeting item, the controls on the window should now display the values of what the Meeting item contains. So I want to map the Chairman combo value to the Chairman text property in the Meeting item.

But the chairman combo contents is built from the Students list.

Comment: You bind `comboChairman` with `Students`, which i suppose are not of type `Meeting`, so you can't use a property of `Meeting` as `SelectedItem`. What are you trying to archieve?

Comment: Does my updated question help?

Comment: A bit. What you must do is, in the `Meeting` Setter, load the `Students` collection (i suppose it is a `ObservableCollection`).When you load it, the `comboChairman` will show the loaded Students

Comment: I got it working as per my answer. I am sorted now. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out how to use the popup dialogues in the IDE to help me build my XAML correctly.

I also realised that I was accidently creating properties in the `ViewModel` when I should have been binding to properties within another property that was bound to the `ComboBox`.

So the main ComboBox is now:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboMeetingWeek"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Meetings/, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          DisplayMemberPath="DateMeetingAsText">
</ComboBox>
```

And all the other controls whose content binds to properties within the `Meeting` object look like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboChairman"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Students, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:OtherPrivileges.Chairman}, Converter={StaticResource StudentPrivilegeConvertor}}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Chairman, 
             ElementName=comboMeetingWeek, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             IsEditable="True"/>
```

So the `Students` list is correct because the Chairman ComboBox still has the main **window** `DataContext`.

And the value held in the `ComboBox` (`Text`) is now correctly bound to the right item!